# change a line in a file at the same place using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

My file contains data as indicated below:

```
{ "any1", "aaa.bbb.ccc.1.ddd", "var1" }
{ "any2", "aaa.bbb.ccc.1.eee", "toto" }
{ "an42", "aaa.bbb.ccc.1.fff", "titi" }
{ "an47", "aaa.bbb.ccc.2.eee", "var3" }
{ "any7", "aaa.bbb.ccc.2.ddd", "var12" }
{ "a789", "aaa.bbb.ccc.2.fff", "var14" }
{ "any1", "xxx.yyy.zzz.1.ddd", "var1" }
{ "any2", "xxx.yyy.zzz.1.eee", "toto" }
{ "an42", "xxx.yyy.zzz.1.fff", "titi" }
```

I want to change the line which contains `"aaa.bbb.ccc.2.fff"` with another line `{"any line content"}` at the same place.

So the new file should looks like this

```
{ "any1", "aaa.bbb.ccc.1.ddd", "var1" }
{ "any2", "aaa.bbb.ccc.1.eee", "toto" }
{ "an42", "aaa.bbb.ccc.1.fff", "titi" }
{ "an47", "aaa.bbb.ccc.2.eee", "var3" }
{ "any7", "aaa.bbb.ccc.2.ddd", "var12" }
{"any line content"}
{ "any1", "xxx.yyy.zzz.1.ddd", "var1" }
{ "any2", "xxx.yyy.zzz.1.eee", "toto" }
{ "an42", "xxx.yyy.zzz.1.fff", "titi" }
```

How I can make that with `sed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `/pattern/s/find/replace/` expression, escaping the dots to prevent them matching any character:

```
$ sed '/aaa\.bbb\.ccc\.2\.fff/s/.*/hi/' file
{ "any1", "aaa.bbb.ccc.1.ddd", "var1" }
{ "any2", "aaa.bbb.ccc.1.eee", "toto" }
{ "an42", "aaa.bbb.ccc.1.fff", "titi" }
{ "an47", "aaa.bbb.ccc.2.eee", "var3" }
{ "any7", "aaa.bbb.ccc.2.ddd", "var12" }
hi
{ "any1", "xxx.yyy.zzz.1.ddd", "var1" }
{ "any2", "xxx.yyy.zzz.1.eee", "toto" }
{ "an42", "xxx.yyy.zzz.1.fff", "titi" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `awk` for this:

```
awk '/aaa\.bbb\.ccc\.2\.fff/ {$0="{\"any line content\"}"}1' file
{ "any1", "aaa.bbb.ccc.1.ddd", "var1" }
{ "any2", "aaa.bbb.ccc.1.eee", "toto" }
{ "an42", "aaa.bbb.ccc.1.fff", "titi" }
{ "an47", "aaa.bbb.ccc.2.eee", "var3" }
{ "any7", "aaa.bbb.ccc.2.ddd", "var12" }
{"any line content"}
{ "any1", "xxx.yyy.zzz.1.ddd", "var1" }
{ "any2", "xxx.yyy.zzz.1.eee", "toto" }
{ "an42", "xxx.yyy.zzz.1.fff", "titi" }
```